# Install an ORM into an custom PHP5 framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm, doctrine

What is the procedure to install an ORM component such as Doctrine into an existing custom PHP5 MVC framework?
What are the minimal requirement in terms of framework architecture and fonctionalities ?
What are the possible problems to face ?
Would it be problematic to have side by side tables generated by the ORM and some by "old fashioned " SQL request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORM is simply an abstraction for your database interactions. The Doctrine ORM wraps PHPs PDO library and adds some useful abstractions. To implement Doctrine into your existing framework you'll need to download the code and put it into a directory in your project. If you're already using third party libraries, place it there. If not, create a `vendors` directory and drop doctrine in it. You can follow the Doctrine documentation for installation and configuration details.

Once you've implemented doctrine, your task will be to update existing database interactions. If all database interactions are already handled through models, you should be able to write an abstract or interface base class for your models. From there, models can be updated to implement Doctrine methods for interaction.

If you have SQL scattered around the app, you should probably decouple the database interactions and isolate them into models then follow the process described above.

There is nothing about using the ORM that will prevent existing database interactions from operating, but that is very messy and should be avoided if at all possible.